# How to select multiple elements with queryselector

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make something that the user select a color with the first input and it changes the background color of the body, and when the user select a color in the "Subtitles color" input it should change the color of both , but the second  isn't changing the color. Can someone help me? I have tried using getElementById and getElementsByClassName and it won't even select the first child.

```js
const ColorPicker  = document.querySelector("#input1");
const ColorCode = document.querySelector("#input1").value;
const Body = document.querySelector("#fundoPagina");
        
const ColorPicker4  = document.querySelector("#input4");
const ColorCode4 = document.querySelector("#input4").value;
const subtitulo = document.querySelector("h2");
        
        
        // Change color function
        const changeColor = (evt) => {
          const selectedColor = evt.currentTarget.value;
          ColorCode.value = selectedColor;
          Body.style.backgroundColor = selectedColor;
        };
        
        const changeColor4 = (evt) => {
        const selectedColor4 = evt.currentTarget.value;
        ColorCode4.value = selectedColor4;
        subtitulo.style.color = selectedColor4;
    };
        
        // Add the Event to your input
        ColorPicker .addEventListener("input", changeColor);
        ColorPicker4 .addEventListener("input", changeColor4);
```

```css
    .inputContent {
    display: flex; 
    text-align:center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 15px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(66, 66, 66);
    max-width: 890px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    background: rgb(219, 219, 219);
}

#inputColor {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column!important;
    align-items: center;
}

#inputColor>p {
    font-size: 12px;
}

#fundoCaixa {
    max-width: 890px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px solid rgb(66, 66, 66);
    margin-top: 15px;
    background: rgb(89, 156, 187);
    padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<body id="fundoPagina">
    <div class="inputContent">
        <div id="inputColor"><input type="color" value="#000" id="input1"></input><p>Cor do fundo da página</p></div>
                <div id="inputColor"><input type="color" value="#000" id="input4"></input><p>Subtitles Color</p></div>

    </div>
    <main id="fundoCaixa">
        <h1 id="tituloPrincipal">Linguagens de Programação</h1>
        <p id="paragrafo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ipsum nihil incidunt sint laudantium est earum optio ducimus in facilis quisquam. Tempore iste dignissimos.</p>
    <h2 id="linguagemC" class="subtitulo">Linguagem C</h2>
    <h2 id="linguagemPascal" class="subtitulo">Linguagem Pascal</h2>

</main>
</body>
```

I'm trying to make something that the user select a color with the first input and it changes the background color of the body, and when the user select a color in the "Subtitles color" input it should change the color of both , but the second  isn't changing the color. Can someone help me? I have tried using getElementById and getElementsByClassName and it won't even select the first child.

```js
const ColorPicker  = document.querySelector("#input1");
const ColorCode = document.querySelector("#input1").value;
const Body = document.querySelector("#fundoPagina");
        
const ColorPicker4  = document.querySelector("#input4");
const ColorCode4 = document.querySelector("#input4").value;
const subtitulo = document.querySelector("h2");
        
        
        // Change color function
        const changeColor = (evt) => {
          const selectedColor = evt.currentTarget.value;
          ColorCode.value = selectedColor;
          Body.style.backgroundColor = selectedColor;
        };
        
        const changeColor4 = (evt) => {
        const selectedColor4 = evt.currentTarget.value;
        ColorCode4.value = selectedColor4;
        subtitulo.style.color = selectedColor4;
    };
        
        // Add the Event to your input
        ColorPicker .addEventListener("input", changeColor);
        ColorPicker4 .addEventListener("input", changeColor4);
```

```css
    .inputContent {
    display: flex; 
    text-align:center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 15px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(66, 66, 66);
    max-width: 890px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    background: rgb(219, 219, 219);
}

#inputColor {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column!important;
    align-items: center;
}

#inputColor>p {
    font-size: 12px;
}

#fundoCaixa {
    max-width: 890px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px solid rgb(66, 66, 66);
    margin-top: 15px;
    background: rgb(89, 156, 187);
    padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<body id="fundoPagina">
    <div class="inputContent">
        <div id="inputColor"><input type="color" value="#000" id="input1"></input><p>Cor do fundo da página</p></div>
                <div id="inputColor"><input type="color" value="#000" id="input4"></input><p>Subtitles Color</p></div>

    </div>
    <main id="fundoCaixa">
        <h1 id="tituloPrincipal">Linguagens de Programação</h1>
        <p id="paragrafo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ipsum nihil incidunt sint laudantium est earum optio ducimus in facilis quisquam. Tempore iste dignissimos.</p>
    <h2 id="linguagemC" class="subtitulo">Linguagem C</h2>
    <h2 id="linguagemPascal" class="subtitulo">Linguagem Pascal</h2>

</main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `querySelectorAll`

`querySelectorAll` will get a nodelist, use `foreach` to change style for all of selected elements.

And you actually only need one function to do this, you can change the style attribute and selected element by `data-attribute` in `<input/>`.

```js
const colorPickers = document.querySelectorAll('input')
colorPickers.forEach(colorPicker => {
  colorPicker.addEventListener('input', ({
    target
  }) => {
    const value = target.value
    const elements = target.getAttribute('data-element')
    const style = target.getAttribute('data-style')
    document.querySelectorAll(elements).forEach(elem => {
      elem.style[style] = value
    })
  })
})
```

```css
.inputContent {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 15px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(66, 66, 66);
  max-width: 890px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background: rgb(219, 219, 219);
}

#inputColor {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column !important;
  align-items: center;
}

#inputColor>p {
  font-size: 12px;
}

#fundoCaixa {
  max-width: 890px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid rgb(66, 66, 66);
  margin-top: 15px;
  background: rgb(89, 156, 187);
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<body id="fundoPagina">
  <div class="inputContent">
    <div><input type="color" value="#000" data-element="body" data-style="backgroundColor" />
      <p>Cor do fundo da página</p>
    </div>
    <div><input type="color" value="#000" data-element="h2" data-style="color" />
      <p>Subtitles Color</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <main id="fundoCaixa">
    <h1 id="tituloPrincipal">Linguagens de Programação</h1>
    <p id="paragrafo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ipsum nihil incidunt sint laudantium est earum optio ducimus in facilis quisquam. Tempore iste dignissimos.</p>
    <h2 id="linguagemC" class="subtitulo">Linguagem C</h2>
    <h2 id="linguagemPascal" class="subtitulo">Linguagem Pascal</h2>
  </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some minor change in your code.
that change highlighted with `<-- edit`

```js
const ColorPicker  = document.querySelector("#input1");
const ColorCode = document.querySelector("#input1").value;
const Body = document.querySelector("#fundoPagina");
        
const ColorPicker4  = document.querySelector("#input4");
const ColorCode4 = document.querySelector("#input4").value;
const subtitulo = document.querySelectorAll("h2"); //<-- edit
 
        const changeColor = (evt) => {
          const selectedColor = evt.currentTarget.value;
          ColorCode.value = selectedColor;
          Body.style.backgroundColor = selectedColor;
        };
        
        const changeColor4 = (evt) => {
        const selectedColor4 = evt.currentTarget.value;
        ColorCode4.value = selectedColor4;
        subtitulo.forEach( h => h.style.color = selectedColor4  ) //<-- edit
    };
        
        // Add the Event to your input
        ColorPicker .addEventListener("input", changeColor);
        ColorPicker4 .addEventListener("input", changeColor4);
```

```css
.inputContent {
    display: flex; 
    text-align:center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 15px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(66, 66, 66);
    max-width: 890px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    background: rgb(219, 219, 219);
}

#inputColor {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column!important;
    align-items: center;
}

#inputColor>p {
    font-size: 12px;
}

#fundoCaixa {
    max-width: 890px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px solid rgb(66, 66, 66);
    margin-top: 15px;
    background: rgb(89, 156, 187);
    padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<body id="fundoPagina">
    <div class="inputContent">
        <div id="inputColor"><input type="color" value="#000" id="input1"></input><p>Cor do fundo da página</p></div>
                <div id="inputColor"><input type="color" value="#000" id="input4"></input><p>Subtitles Color</p></div>

    </div>
    <main id="fundoCaixa">
        <h1 id="tituloPrincipal">Linguagens de Programação</h1>
        <p id="paragrafo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ipsum nihil incidunt sint laudantium est earum optio ducimus in facilis quisquam. Tempore iste dignissimos.</p>
    <h2 id="linguagemC" class="subtitulo">Linguagem C</h2>
    <h2 id="linguagemPascal" class="subtitulo">Linguagem Pascal</h2>

</main>
</body>
```